# Custom Knockout template not picked in checkout - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I wanted to show a message on checkout page (above the 'complete checkout' button) only if customer is on certain store views (id_id or id_en). Here what I have done so far. Please help me to find what I am doing wrong.

app/code/Sample/Chmodule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="testmsg" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Sample_Chmodule/js/view/test-message</item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">testmsg</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Sample_Chmodule/test-message</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html is overridden in my module (Sample_Chmodule) and added below content

```
    <div class="test-message">
        <p>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('testmsg') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </p>
    </div>
```

app/code/Sample/Chmodule/view/frontend/web/js/view/test-message

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        showSampleText: function(){
            if(window.checkoutConfig.storeCode == "id_en" || window.checkoutConfig.storeCode == "id_id"){
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

app/code/Sample/Chmodule/view/frontend/web/template/test-message.html

```
<!-- ko if: showSampleText() -->
    <!-- ko i18n: "Sample text which I need to show just above the checkout button." -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Once I follow all of above steps, I could see below content on inspect element. But the knockout component configured in xml (testmsg) is not showing

```
<div class="test-message">
        <p>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('testmsg') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </p>
    </div>
```

and when I run window.checkoutConfig.storeCode on console, it shows the correct storecode (id_en, id_id etc)

Your advise on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a mistake when adding dependencies in component js file. The type of **Component** as 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default' was wrong and I corrected it to **'uiComponent'** then started to work fine. Find the correct js file content below. Writting up it here as this might help someone else in the future

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        showDokuNotice: function(){
            if(window.checkoutConfig.storeCode == "id_en" || window.checkoutConfig.storeCode == "id_id"){
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```